# NSEntityDescription does not have member named "name"

Tags: swift, ios8, ios8.1

I'm new to iOS and editing an old to-do list I created with a tutorial a while back. A few issues after occurred upgrading to the newest version of xCode, and I've seemed to resolve all of them besides this one:

"NSEntityDescription does not have member named 'name'"

I've tried several different variants for the entity name from other suggestions but they only seemed to apply to names that are assigned by the programmer rather than passed in by the user.

```
func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity
    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name, inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    newManagedObject.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "timeStamp")

    // Save the context.
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) {
        abort()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the template code created by a new swift project:

```
let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
```

Looks like you need to add the '!' in two places.

Comment: This can cause your app to crash if the forced unwrapping of name is nil. You would do better to check first.